# Can't find job as entry-level leaving in 2 years

Tags: career-development

My situation is that I just graduated with a Bachelor's in CS about a month ago, but I am also planning on going to medical school after about 2 more years (due to required courses). I chose CS, because you can't do much with a degree like Biology and I wanted to have a good backup plan. Plus, I enjoy CS.

I've been rejected about 5 or 6 times now after what I perceived to be really good interviews, and I assume it's almost certainly because I tell them I am planning on leaving in 2 years. I think I'm very good for an entry-level employee - but I'm still entry-level. Not surprisingly, not many places want to take on and train an entry-level employee who isn't going to stay with them and be promoted from within. Entry-level temporary jobs are pretty non-existent, too.

Getting a CS job in the meantime is important to me for two equally very important reasons:

1. I want to make money in the meantime. Med school isn't free.
2. I want to move ahead in my CS "career." I may choose to continue to pursue it (even if that's just in the form of hobbies - but hobbies in CS often earn you money, as well) even if I go to med school, and I don't want to "lose it" by "not using it." Like I said, I enjoy CS, and I want to get better at it so that I can maybe make something of it. There's also the possibility of combining my two passions someday.

I think that, even if I can't get a CS job, I will somehow pursue CS. **My primary concern is if there is any possibility of someplace hiring me in this situation, or should I instead focus my efforts on freelance things**, like learning Android, or something - something that can earn me money in the meantime, and something that is useful? Making money in my "time off" is important to me. I have often heard that you can be a great programmer just by personally pursuing it, so maybe that is an option (i.e. getting a job with no degree, just experience messing around). If it's all I can get, I would even be okay with a "code mill" job that doesn't think much of its employees, as long as it gets me some cash in the meantime and something I can write on my resume as experience.

Furthermore, can I still learn important things on my own? For instance, I had never even heard of J2EE, struts, etc. before interviews, so I don't know if the only real way to learn that is in a work environment. I want to still be valuable as a programmer when I come out of (and throughout) med school, and I want to still be able to do things in CS. I just don't want to miss important details that I would get in a job. I want to be able to get a job that is above entry-level, so I'm not seen so much as an investment and can more easily get a job if that's what I need to do.

Comment: Uh, so **stop telling them that you're going to leave in 2 years**? You don't know if you'll even be accepted by any med schools, and you can't say for certain what will be going on in your life 2 years from now.

Comment: @Caleb- Seconded. I could see informing your prospective employers if you were planning on leaving in a matter of *months*. But two years? That doesn't merit advance notice, especially for an entry-level job.

Answer (score 4):

> I've been rejected about 5 or 6 times now after what I perceived to be
>   really good interviews

I have to point out that while you don't need to share what you might or might not end up doing in two years (Even if you are 100% sure right now, lots of things can change in two years time), it may not be reason you were not selected after a good interview. You are in competition with other people and while you had a good interview, someone else could have had an even better one. Further people are evaluating you on how you will fit into their team not just your technical answers. So while you may have thought you did well, you may have actually said something that they decided made you a poor fit. And sometimes they get a hiring freeze between the interview and the offer and can't hire anyone at all not even that guy who did great.

In other words, what I am saying is don't stop looking at other things you can do to improve your interview performance.

I might also point out that if you look for development jobs in the medical sector, you  might have some people you impressed in the time you were there who will help you get into medical school when the time comes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to answer this somewhat generically.  I realize this question is a migration, and I really want to get some answers out there, but it's also not great, as a forum to be giving career advice that only works on a case by case basis.

### How absolutely certain are you?

I talk to a lot of folks who will say they are "absolutely" pursuing education for a new career in the 2-5 year time frame where that number continuously drifts.  There no single easy answer on certainty, but that's the first baseline.

I dislike the idea that you want to lie to employers if you are certain that your stay will be short - it's not illegal, or even unethical, but I believe in karma and that bad impressions are lasting impressions - so if it somes out that your plans were dead certain and you lied, it could mean a negative repurcission.

The spectrum of certainty for me would be:

- VERY CERTAIN = definite financial commitments made, serious steps taken along the path (acceptance letter in hand), other life arrangements are in place (you've purchased property near your target medical school... your spouse has arranged to be the primary provider 2 years hence... etc).
- NOT CERTAIN = still reviewing schools, financial plan not firmly decided, not sure where you'll live or how your other life logistics work, current family arrangements are such that the decisions of others would drastically change whether this was 2 years away or 5.

If you fall more into "NOT CERTAIN" than don't talk about life decisions that you are uncertain of with future employers.  That means everything - future education, marriage, relocation, pregnancy, health conditions, etc.

### Employer Perspective

I wouldn't be surprised if, on hearing your intent to move on in 2 years, employers are not so interested in making a commitment on a new employee who is also quite green in the field.  Employees new to a career path in almost any knowledge working field have a serious learning curve in just about any organization.  I expect, in most cases, that a new college grad (especially one with no interning experience), will:

- Take 6 months before they are 50% productive
- Take 1 year to become 80-90% productive
- Consume ~4-6 weeks total of team support time in the first year.

My general metric is that in 3 years, I'll have capitalized on my investment in the person.  I'll be reaping "profit" by 5 years.

If you want to sell yourself and be honest about the plan to leave in 2 years, you're going to have to sell a case where this cost/productivity tradeoff is different.  Unfortunately, with very little job experience, it's hard to prove you are a self-starter, and you don't have the depth to be the perfect expert consultant right off the bat.  I don't want to say it's impossible, but I'd say that the options are very much centered around your unique qualities or interests.

### Other Options:

I generally guide new college grads away from "consulting" or "contracting" - usually contractors/consultants are more expensive than entry level and expected to hit the ground running harder and faster than most new college grads can manage.  You may be the one savant who can do this, but you're going to have to prove your savant-like capabilities in an even more competitive arena than the regular full-time employee field.

Instead, consider:

- freelance for small business - small scope projects for small business that have a small beginning and ending - largely based on your ability to communicate and negotiate a fee.  You can get started here as a volunteer for a non-profit, build some skills with working with customers, and move into for-pay freelancing.
- part time/hourly - gigs that are willing to pay part time or at an hourly rate *may* be more flexible and up for someone who is more willing to roll with the ebb and flow of demand.  The risk is lower for them, as they aren't paying for a full salary and banking on you becoming productive.
- in any situation where you are paid per-project, or per-chunk of functionality - you remove the cost of your learning curve - if you get paid $400 it takes you 10 hours to learn it and 10 hours to do it, you get paid $20/hour, if it takes you 30 hours to learn it and 10 hours to do it, it paid you $10/hour - the risk is on you, not the company who paid $400 for this thing.  The hard part is convincing the customer that you know enough about their work that you can do it on time and competently.  Just like a car dealer, an autoshop, Jiffy Lube and the neighbor kid next door will all charge different rates for an oil change - the rate has a lot to do with the professionalism, ease of use and perceived competency of the service provider.
- Sitations where you don't need to quit to go to school.  If the job might let you work remote, move to part time, or otherwise accomodate your education, you may not HAVE to quit the new job to go back to school.  Not as crazy as it sounds.  I didn't have to quit my internship my senior year undergrad - I went from full time to partime and worked hourly from a remote site (my dorm).

### The Yardstick

Realize that if you are comparing yourself to your friends who are planning on a long term commitment to the same career path, that you are using the wrong yard stick.  You are adding conditions to the job that they are not - they are looking for a job they can grow into.  You are looking for a job you can leave in 2 years.  These are very different goals.   As easily different as asking for a dramatically higher salary or other benefit that isn't normally provided in your career context.

Answer (score 1):

> My primary concern is if there is any possibility of someplace hiring
>   me in this situation

There's *always* a possibility of being hired - it only takes one willing employer!

It seems like you have several options at your disposal:

- Avoid telling potential employers that you plan to leave in 2 years
- Continue to seek employment with an employer who doesn't care
- Consider temp work, rather than a "permanent" employer

Of these choices, I recommend the third option - consider temp work.

Based on my past experience hiring people, I think you are correct that few employers will want to bring on an entry-level person, train them, then see them leave within 2 years. I know when I hire someone it is a major commitment for me and my company - one that I don't want to waste on someone who isn't going to be around for the long haul. That said, there are probably a few out there - only one month of looking and 5 or 6 rejections in this economy doesn't mean the end.

I never recommend lying or intentionally withholding information, so I'd be iffy about just not telling potential employers about your plans. That sort of information tends to get around quickly anyway, so unless you are really good about not talking to people, your new employer will eventually find out - and you could lose your good reputation.

Whenever someone is not confident of their future situation, I recommend short temporary gigs, until the situation clears up. In your case, you may be able to find temp jobs, even at an entry level, where what you plan to do in 2 years won't matter at all. I've brought in several people in similar situations in the past, and it has worked out well each time (although there was one person who I tried hard to convince to stick around but failed).

Good luck!